# How to check if a particular address is already present in an array

Tags: contract-development, addresses

I know a similar question has been asked before but I want to understand where am I going wrong in terms of logic for the code below. I am building a lottery contract where if an address has been added once then that address can no longer play again. I am using a for loop to check if the address is present.
When I deploy the contract and run the addPlayer function I get an error stating: `transact to lottery.addPlayer errored: VM error: invalid opcode. invalid opcode The execution might have thrown. Debug the transaction to get more information.`

```
contract lottery
{
        //Defining the Owner
            address Owner;
            constructor() public
            {   
                 Owner = msg.sender;    
                 
            }
    
        // Defining players
        
            struct person
            {
                string name;
                uint age;
            }
    
        // One to one mapping of player and its address    
            mapping (address => person) players;
            mapping(string => bool) userExists;


        // creating a list/array of players    
        address[] playersAddressList;


        // Tracking balance;
            uint public balance=0;
            
                   
        //Function to add a player to the lottery
        bool public flag=false;
        
        
        function addPlayer(string memory a, uint b) public payable
        {
               //Checking if the player already exists in the list
                
                for(uint i=0; i<=playersAddressList.length; i++)
                {
                    if(playersAddressList[i] == msg.sender)
                    {
                       flag=true;
                       break;
                    }
                }
         
                require (flag==false);
                
                address creator = msg.sender;
                playersAddressList.push(creator);
                
                balance = balance + msg.value;
                require (msg.value >= 1 ether);
                
                person memory newPerson;
    
                newPerson.name = a;
                newPerson.age = b;
        
                players[creator] = newPerson;
        }
     // Function to get the player details'
      function getPlayerDetails(uint a) public view returns(string memory, uint)
        {
            address playersAddress = playersAddressList[a];
            return (players[playersAddress].name, players[playersAddress].age);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is with line: `for(uint i=0; i<=playersAddressList.length; i++)`. Arrays are zero-based so you are iterating too far.

If for example your array has 3 entries the length will be 3. But your loop checks for 4 entries (at indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3) - the last index doesn't exist so it crashes.

Just change your condition to `for(uint i = 0; i < playersAddressList.length; i++)` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As the amount of players grows, that loop will consume more and more gas. If you get a lot of players, it will start to cost too much in transaction fees.

If the amount of players should be unlimited, you should maintain a mapping to track which addresses are already participating:

```
mapping(address => bool) public playersMapping;
```

That way you can run one if-statement in O(1) gas complexity instead of the loop in O(n) gas complexity:

```
if (playersMapping[playerAddress]) {
```

You might be able to use the `players` mapping that you already have

Comment: Thanks @Jesbus that was very helpful.